# Usage of "to" after "equals"

Tags: prepositions

> So totally, historic energy usage is 3393.866 kWh. This equals **to** 791 kg CO<sub>2</sub> emissions.

Is the preposition 'to' necessary in the above sentence?

Comment: Either **this is equal to** or **this equals**. One or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I elaborate on what @Ronald Sole has rightly commented.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/equal) defines *equal*.

> equal adjective (SAME) B1
> the same in amount, number, or size:
> One litre **is equal to** 1.76 imperial pints [emphasis added].

Note the use of **to** in such a construction.

As a verb, it is either a linking verb or a transitive verb. Its use as a linking verb is shown below.

> equal verb [L only + noun, T] (BE THE SAME)
> to be the same in value or amount as something else:
> 16 ounces **equals** one pound [emphasis added]

We could hence say

> This is equal to 791 kg CO2 emission.
>
> This equals 791 kg CO2 emission.